# Changing M_MMAP_THRESHOLD and allocating memory above and below it

Tags: c++, malloc, mmap

I recently learned that when we call `malloc` and ask for more memory than the `M_MMAP_THRESHOLD`, the system will allocate a memory segment using `mmap`instead of using `malloc` and allocating on the heap. The following code was written to check that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>
#include <malloc.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  const auto M = 4; // M = 4, 32, 64
  const auto threshold = M * 1024; 
  if (mallopt(M_MMAP_THRESHOLD, threshold) != 1) {
    throw invalid_argument{"mallopt failed: "s + strerror(errno)};
  }
  
  auto below = malloc(threshold - 8);
  auto above = malloc(threshold + 8);
  cout << "&below: " << below << "\n";
  cout << "&above: " << above << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

The results that I get when using these three different values for `M` are:

**M=4**
Both memory blocks allocated on the heap. (unexpected)

```
&below: 0x558b85810eb0
&above: 0x558b85811eb0
```

**M=16**
One block on the heap, one mapping in VM space. (expected)

```
&below: 0x557b31501eb0
&above: 0x7f0b0d66d010
```

**M=32**
Two mappings on VM space. (unexpected)

```
&below: 0x7f1fee27d010
&above: 0x7f1fedd1c010
```

My question is why don't we see the expected result in all cases but only at the second?

Comment: Manpage  here says it should work but that doesn't seem to be the case. You have to look at the source of your libc.